# Hiding row in adf table based on Transient attribute not working

Tags: java, rendering, oracle-adf, jdeveloper

I have an `JSF` page where the user can insert new row in `View object`. this `View object` contains a `Transient` attribute which tells if the record is newly created or not.

In the same page I have an `adf table` that is bounded to the mentioned `view object`. This table should display only the newly created records. my approach is to use `expression language` in the `rendered` property to hide all other rows that are not newly created. I changed the render property for the table columns as: `rendered="#{row.bindings.RowStatus.inputValue eq 'new'}"` but the table shows nothing.

Then, I tried to change the `rendered` property not for the column but to the `outputText` inside it in the same way. It did work but the problem is that the empty row is still showing.

So, Basically by that I am not hiding the whole row, instead I am hiding the text in side the rows and the rows with empty spaces is still showing in the page.

This the Table from `JSF` page where the `rendered` property is applied on `outputText` inside the column:

```
<af:table value="#{bindings.UplodedFilesView1.collectionModel}" var="row"
                          rows="#{bindings.UplodedFilesView1.rangeSize}"
                          binding="#{CreatSR_UserBean.fileTable}">

    <af:column sortProperty="#{bindings.UplodedFilesView1.hints.FileName.name}" 
      headerText="File Name" id="c1">

          <af:outputText value="#{row.bindings.FileName.inputValue}" id="it1"
          rendered="#{row.bindings.RowStatus.inputValue eq'new'}"/>

   </af:column>

   </af:table>
```

> I am using Jdeveloper 11.1.2.3 with ADF Technology

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its to late to hide rows after stamping the `row set`. The problem could be solve by filtering the `View object` based on the `Transient` attribute in the `Page Binding` section.

The detailed steps are mentioned in this thread: [How to Filter View object based on Transient attribute](https://community.oracle.com/thread/3524229)